# recorrer objetos JSON e identificarlos

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un JSON que me trae varios objetos como podría recorrerlos y identificarlos para así trabajar con cada uno de ellos por separado o traer cualquiera de los elementos que lo componen. sinceramente siempre se me ha complicado esto de trabajar con objetos :(

```js
function traer(){
    var b = $.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1aujl6",
    function (todo) {
     var a = todo;
        console.log(a);
    }, "json");
}

traer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: mira https://stackoverflow.com/a/11846539/7700985 hay varias formas de recorrer un objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes recorrerlo con `jQuery.each()`.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function traer(){
    var b = $.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1aujl6",
    function (todo) {
     var a = todo.data;
     $.each(a, function(i, obj) {
       console.log(obj.name);
       console.log("Price: " + obj.quotes.USD.price);
     });
        
    }, "json");
}

traer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: holis Algran, gracias como siempre... estupendo, como accederia con este mismo ejemplo a los elementos que estan dentro de quotes.USD

Comment: ya edite la respuesta

Comment: fantastico.... sin palabras.. gracias jajajaja <3

Comment: esto me imagino que crea un bucle for  `$.each(a, function(i, obj)` y asi podemos recorrer todos los elementos que trae el JSON

Comment: Correcto, en general para acceder las propiedades de un objeto usas `objeto.propiedad`.  En tu caso la informacion esta en `todo.data` asi que eso es lo que tienes que recorrer con el `$.each()`